# is it possible to get the dartdoc to show comments on properties

Tags: dart

I am using the menu item in the DartEditor to generate documentation.

The following works fine:

```
dynamic _parent;
///   Reference to parent of this variable
dynamic get parent => _parent;
```

Function comments also work just fine.

However, if it is just a public property with no defined getter:

```
///   True if the variable is static
bool isStatic = false;
```

then I get no documentation.

Are the flags sent to dartdoc from the DartEditor configurable (if so how)?

Do I need to change the default configuration to get the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed recently. It should roll out in this coming week's editor build.